# Enter shell script output in a Xml file

Tags: shell

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>The maximum number of map tasks that will be run
  simultaneously by a task tracker.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run
  simultaneously by a task tracker.
  </description>
</property>
```

i want to change just (mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum value )by  my value of my script output ,and dont change the other value(The maximum number of reduce tasks )beyond it , How can i do this?!

Comment: Can you add an example of your XML file with what part you want to change and how?

Comment: both of that 2 values are in a xml file and i want change the first one by my shell script output, how can i do this?     like this                 <property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>The maximum number of map tasks that will be run
  simultaneously by a task tracker.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run
  simultaneously by a task tracker.
  </description>
</property>
first 2 by value 4

Comment: Why are you posting your same question more than once? http://superuser.com/questions/962975/how-to-write-a-shell-script-output-to-an-xml-file

Comment: When you post example XML, please mark it as CODE - i.e. paste it, then mark it and click the `{}`-button just above the text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your XML file seems not to be complete, it is missing something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top>
...
</top>
```

If you add that you can use `xmlstarlet` to modify the XML file.

```
xmlstarlet ed -P -u "/top/property/name[text()='mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum']/../value" -v 4 nameofxmlfile
```

For Information what this does you can `man xmlstarlet` and `xmlstarlet ed --help`.

xmlstarlet will run in edit mode (`ed`), it will load the file `nameofxmlfile`, keep whitespace nodes (`-P`) and it will change the value of a node to 4 (`-v 4`). The node to modify is identified by the XPath `"/top/property/name[text()='mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum']/../value"`. This is to be read from left to right: start at top level (`/`), go into `top` node, go into every `property` subnode, go into `name` sub node, filter for only these names which have the given text (`[text()='mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum']`), go up one node (`..`, back to property again), then go down into `value` subnode.

The result will be printed to stdout. If you want xmlstarlet to modify the file instead, then add `-L` after `-P`.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Use an XML parser

If you’re going to manipulate XML,
you should use a tool designed specifically for that purpose. 
(There are no such tools built in to Unix.) 
This has been discussed repeatedly on Stack Exchange:

- Stack Overflow:

  - [Why it’s not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML:
    a formal explanation in layman’s terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/1672723)
  - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1672723)
  - [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML
    with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1672723)
  - [How extract specific elements of an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11599111/1672723)
- Unix & Linux:

  - [Text between two tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64645/23408)
  - [How to parse XML to CSV with a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65648/23408)

XMLStarlet (which [Werner Henze mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/963063/150988)) seems to be widely recommended.

## 2. However, …

… if your data are well-behaved (e.g., one pair of matching tags per line;
no strings that look like tags but aren’t; etc…),
you may be able to do it with standard Unix commands.

### 2.1 awk

```
awk '
        /<name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum<\/name>/ { inzone=1 }
        inzone && /<value>.*<\/value>/ { sub(/<value>.*<\/value>/, "<value>4</value>"); inzone=0 }
        /<\/property>/ { inzone=0 }
        1
    '
```

- Upon recognizing the `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` string,
  set the `inzone` flag
  to indicate that we want to change the next `value` we see.
- If we see a `value` while we’re in the zone (`inzone`),
  replace it with the new value and zero the `inzone` flag.
- If we see the end of a `property`, clear the flag,
  because we’re no longer in the `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` data.

### 2.2 sed

```
sed '/<name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum<\/name>/ {
        : loop
        n
        s/<value>.*<\/value>/<value>4<\/value>/
        t
        /<\/property>/b
        b loop
    }'
```

- Upon recognizing the `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` string,
  enter the `{…}` command block.
- Start the block with a label (`loop`),
  so we can execute the following commands multiple times
  (until we find the `value`).
- Go to the next line.
- Try to substitute the value.
- If the substitute succeeded, jump to the end of the loop.
- If we see the end of a `property`, branch to the end of the loop,
  because we’re no longer in the `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` data.
- Otherwise, branch to the beginning of the loop, and repeat the above.